# How do I get a daily average for one month?

Tags: t-sql, average, common-table-expression

How do I return the daily average for an entire month?

```
select count(distinct people_id) 
from #enrollments_PreviousMonth
where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' 
AND actual_date between '4/1/13' and '5/1/13'
```

Above is a portion of my current code.  I want to get a distinct count of people_id for each day in April.  Then I want to average these counts for the month of April.  For example, if the count was 764 on April 1 and 763 on April 2, then I would sum 764 and 763 = 1527.  Likewise, I would sum every day in April.  Finally I would divide by number of days in April to get my daily average.  What's the most efficient TSQL to accomplish this?  Is there a CTE I could use for this or some other standard SQL operator?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use something like this

```
SELECT round(Cast(count(people_id)as float) / Cast(DateDiff(day, '4/1/13', '4/6/13')as float), 2) as average
    FROM #enrollments_PreviousMonth
    WHERE program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' 
        AND actual_date between '4/1/13' and '5/1/13'
    GROUP BY people_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH list AS (
select actual_date,count(distinct people_id) cnt
from #enrollments_PreviousMonth
where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' 
AND actual_date between '4/1/13' and '5/1/13'
GROUP  BY actual_date )
SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM list
```

Comment: Make sure you cast cnt to float when averaging or average will return an int rather than a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, distinctPeopleByDate))
FROM
(
    select actual_date, count(distinct people_id) as distinctPeopleByDate
    from #enrollments_PreviousMonth
    where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' 
    and actual_date between '4/1/13' and '5/1/13'
    group by actual_date
) x
```